# Not able to access imported class using * wildcard but able to use same class when imported with full qualified name

Tags: java, import, package, wildcard, importerror

- I am new to java please help me
- I am having trouble using the * wild card in my import statements
- I compiled the javatesting1 class using javac -d . javatesting1.java and also got the .class file in test1 package
- here is my folder structure [click on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiR6t.png)
- When i compile javatesting2 while using import statement with * I am getting the following error

```
    javac javatesting2.java
    javatesting2.java:2: error: cannot access javatesting1
    class testingclass extends javatesting1
                               ^
    bad source file: .\javatesting1.java
    file does not contain class javatesting1
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.


    javatesting2.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(a);
                           ^
    symbol:   variable a
    location: class testingclass

    2 errors
```

Here is my code

```java
    package test1;
    public class javatesting1
    {
         protected int a=45;
         int b=78;
    }
```

```java
    //I am not able to use the javatesting1 class when i use test1.* instead of test1.javatesting1
    
    // the below code is on another file in the same directory
    import test1.javatesting1;
    class testingclass extends javatesting1
    {
        public void meth1()
        {
            System.out.println(a);
           // System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
    public class javatesting2
    { 
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
                  testingclass obj=new testingclass();
                  obj.meth1();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Since you are declaring class javatesting1 to be in a package test1, Java expects to find that class in a folder named like the package in order to scan it (using the wildcard).
I have tested your code, importing using wildcard *, with a folder structure like this

> folder
>
> - javatesting2.java
> - test1
>
>   > - javatesting1.java

Try editing your folder structure.

Also please try do adhere to coding conventions: class names should be named using CamelCase, e.g. JavaTesting1

Comment: thank you for your response i have the same folder structure as you said and had the same error I have included the folder structure in the image please check it

Comment: You have to put `javatesting1.java`inside folder `test1`: since you are compiling source code, Java expects to find .java files in the folder

Comment: thank you siberio for taking time and clarifying my question it works now with out any errors but i still have some small doubt if it is checking for the source code then why importing test1.javatesting1 without wild card is working even though the source code is not present in test1 package is it trying to check the source code first in test1 package and after not finding it ,it is trying to find it in current folder is it correct this is my assumption btw?

Comment: It could be. This is taken from Java docs though
`You should arrange source files in a directory tree that reflects their package tree.` `By default, the compiler puts each class file in the same directory as its source file.`
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: Thank you for all your assistance Siberio,my doubt has been clarified 

Comment: Please consider to accept this answer, or write yourself an answer that can close this question :)

Comment: sure siberio 